# How to customize hash function for pair<int,int> in unordered_set using lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, unordered-set

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    function<bool(vector<int>&,vector<int>&)> cmp=[](vector<int>&a,vector<int>&b)->bool{
        return a[0]>b[0];
    };
    priority_queue<vector<int>,vector<vector<int>>,decltype(cmp)> q(cmp); //Fine

    
    
    function<size_t(pair<int, int>&)> pair_hash = [](pair<int, int>& p) -> size_t {
        return hash<int>()(p.first) ^ hash<int>()(p.second);
    };
    
    unordered_set<pair<int, int>, decltype(pair_hash)> blocks(pair_hash); //Error
}
```

I wonder why `unordered_set` can not use a lambda expression for a customized hash function.

At first I use this:

```
struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator () (pair<T1, T2> const &pair) const
    {
        size_t h1 = hash<T1>()(pair.first); 
        size_t h2 = hash<T2>()(pair.second);
        return h1 ^ h2;
    }
};

unordered_set<pair<int,int>, pair_hash> blocks; //Fine
```

The above code run well. So I wanted to convert it to a lambda expression. But I failed. I just want to know how to write a proper lambda expression about `pair<int,int>` hash function for `unordered_set`.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Could you [edit] and make this a [mcve]?

Comment: [unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set)  doesn't have a constructor taking *only* a hash function.

Answer (score 2):

So `std::unordered_set` does not have a matching constructor for what you are trying to do.

You need to add an additional argument to blocks to specify the size of the set, i.e. the bucket_count:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set

Like this:

```
std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int>, decltype(pair_hash)> blocks(3, pair_hash);
```

Also, I don't think this is a lambda expression:

```
function<size_t(pair<int, int>&)> pair_hash = [](pair<int, int>& p) -> size_t {
    return hash<int>()(p.first) ^ hash<int>()(p.second);
};
```

You create a lambda expression, but then assign it to a `std::function` type object.

I wonder if this works instead:

```
auto pair_hash = [](pair<int, int>& p) -> size_t {
    return hash<int>()(p.first) ^ hash<int>()(p.second);
};
```

Additionally, this function is not the same, since it takes a `const &` as a parameter. Perhaps you need to add a `const` qualification to your lambda?:

```
size_t operator () (pair<T1, T2> const &pair) const
{
    size_t h1 = hash<T1>()(pair.first); 
    size_t h2 = hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    return h1 ^ h2;
}
```